# Cleanest syntax to delete a record in linqtosql

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

What is the best way to delete a database record using LINQ when I have the primary key?

Comment: LINQ has absolutely nothing to do with records or databases. You are thinking of LINQ to SQL.

Comment: This question is misleading. Sounds like you're worried about perf by using the word inefficient.

Comment: Yes I agree, it was a poorly thought out question.

Comment: @Comments above: Read the question - "What is the best way to delete a database record using LINQ when I have the primary key?"...makes it fairly obvious what OP meant.

Comment: Kev, ever hear about editting? :)  The comments are out of date with the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set **update checks** on all your columns to **never** or **when changed**, you can simply attach an instance with the primary key and delete the row without a load.

```
public void DeleteCustomer(int CustomerID)
{
    NorthwindContext c = new NorthwindContext c;
    Customer target = new Customer(){CustomerID = CustomerID};
    c.Customers.Attach(target);
    c.Customers.DeleteOnSubmit(target);
    c.SubmitChanges();                       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That approach is acceptable and typical.

It is a little wasteful because you're requesting the whole record. This cannot be avoided given the DeleteOnSubmit method signature.

Why does LINQ to SQL work this way? The answers obvious if you think about tables that do not have primary keys, or use composite keys. LINQ to SQL needs the whole record for the worst case where it needs to match every object property against the table fields.

But as should be asked for all concerns of performance -  are you absolutely sure this is a performance issue for you?? Where's your profiling proof?

I haven't tried this yet but there might be a way to achieve the same thing with [DataContext.ExecuteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx).

Comment: L2S can't delete a record from a table that doesn't have a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing a select, but improved my syntax which I think was really my concern:

Old:

```
var products = from p in db.Products select p;
db.Products.DeleteOnSubmit(products.Take(1).Single()); <--seemed nasty
db.SubmitChanges();
```

New:

```
Service service = db.Services.Where(s => s.id == serviceID).FirstOrDefault(); <--nicer
db.Services.DeleteOnSubmit(service);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Oh, you meant syntactically inefficient (i.e. ugly), not actually inefficient....

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static Delete(this ITable table, object key)
   { var t = table.GetType();
     var tableName  = t.GetCustomAttributes
                                    (typeof(TableAttribute),false)[0].Name;
     var primaryKey = (from p in t.GetProperties()
                       from c in p.GetCustomAttributes
                                            (typeof(ColumnAttribute),false)
                       where c.IsPrimaryKey
                       select c.Name).Single();
     using (var cmd = table.Context.Connection.CreateCommand())
      { cmd.CommandText = string.Format( "DELETE FROM {0} WHERE {1} = @key"
                                        ,tableName, primaryKey);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@key", key));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        
      }            
   }

/* ... */
dataContext.Table1.Delete(id);
```

Comment: It's just an example. If you accept multiple keys and values as parameters and use the ColumnAttributes to validate, you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can map a stored procedure to a method on the DataContext that deletes a record with a given value for the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the select-delete approach as it's very straight-forward.  As marxidad said, you can map a stored proc if you really want to.  I believe there are plans for ESQL to support insert, update and delete operations in the future.